# i cant boot into lubuntu grub wont show up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu

I have recently installed Lubuntu as a dual boot system with windows 8 and now it just default boots to windows. Ive tried holding shift but nothing happens. If I hold esc I can go to the boot menu but when I try to boot lubuntu from there it comes up as an error. And to clarify I cant get into Linux at all so changing grub from there is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me all the time. As I have a few computers that are dual booting.

Just go to  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair which after you run will allow you to dual boot. If it doesn't then you probably didn't install the software properly.

Best boot with a Live Ubuntu and follow the instructions on the above page.

Comment: @Twitch_Blade If it solved the problem mark the answer as "Solved" so others will not try to answer...